# Reactjs - setState() make all texts of apps flickering

Tags: reactjs, setstate

In component A, I got some setState functions to update states when clicking on some element. What strange happens is that all texts of the whole app flicked. Component A is completed isolated from others. This only happens on Chrome, firefox works just fine :( please help

My MenuButton component code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const InsideLineCommon = styled.span`
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0%;

  &:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary1};
  }

  &:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary1};
  }

`;

const InsideLine = InsideLineCommon.extend`
  &:after {
    left: -200%;
  }

  transition: left ${props => props.theme.animationTime};

  left: ${props => (props.isHalfWidth ? '-100%' : '-200%')};

  ${props => props.isInitialMoving && css`
    left: -50%;
  `}

  ${props => props.isInitialMoving && props.isHalfWidth && css`
    left: 100%;
  `}

  ${props => props.isHorizontalBarsMoving && css`
    left: 200%;
  `}

  ${props => props.isCrossoverBarMoving && css`
    left: -200%;
  `}

  ${props => props.isHalfWidth && css`
    &:after {
      width: 50%;
    }

    &:before {
      width: 50%;
      left: -100%;
    }
  `}
`;

const CommonLine = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
`;

const MiddleLine = CommonLine.extend`
  top: calc(100% / 2 - 7.5%);
`;

const TopLine = CommonLine.extend`
  top: 0px;
`;

const BottomLine = CommonLine.extend`
  bottom: 0px;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.button`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: none;
  background: transparent
  padding: 0px;

  &:focus {
    outline: 0px;
  }
`;

const CrossoverWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;

  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary1};
    transform-origin: center;
    transform:  ${props => (props.isCrossoverBarMoving ? 'rotate(45deg) translate(0%)' : 'rotate(45deg) translate(-130%)')};
    transition: ${props => (!props.isCrossoverBarMoving
      ? `transform ${props.theme.animationTime} 0s`
      : `transform ${props.theme.animationTime} ${props.theme.animationTime}`)};
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary1};
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: ${props => (props.isCrossoverBarMoving ? 'rotate(-45deg) translate(0%)' : 'rotate(-45deg) translate(130%)')};
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition : ${props => (!props.isCrossoverBarMoving
      ? `transform ${props.theme.animationTime} 0s`
      : `transform ${props.theme.animationTime} ${props.theme.animationTime}`)};
  }
`;

class MenuButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isCrossoverBarMoving: false,
      isHorizontalBarsMoving: false,
      isInitialMoving: false,
    };
    this.handleMouseClick = this.handleMouseClick.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseHover = this.handleMouseHover.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        isInitialMoving: true,
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  handleMouseClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isCrossoverBarMoving: !prevState.isCrossoverBarMoving,
    }));
  }

  handleMouseHover() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isHorizontalBarsMoving: !prevState.isHorizontalBarsMoving,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { isHorizontalBarsMoving, isCrossoverBarMoving, isInitialMoving } = { ...this.state };
    return (
      <Wrapper
        onClick={this.handleMouseClick}
        onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
        onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
      >
        <TopLine>
          <InsideLine
            isHorizontalBarsMoving={isHorizontalBarsMoving}
            isCrossoverBarMoving={isCrossoverBarMoving}
            isInitialMoving={isInitialMoving}
          />
        </TopLine>
        <MiddleLine>
          <InsideLine
            isHorizontalBarsMoving={isHorizontalBarsMoving}
            isCrossoverBarMoving={isCrossoverBarMoving}
            isInitialMoving={isInitialMoving}
          />
        </MiddleLine>
        <BottomLine>
          <InsideLine
            isHalfWidth
            isHorizontalBarsMoving={isHorizontalBarsMoving}
            isCrossoverBarMoving={isCrossoverBarMoving}
            isInitialMoving={isInitialMoving}
          />
        </BottomLine>
        <CrossoverWrapper
          isCrossoverBarMoving={isCrossoverBarMoving}
        />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuButton;
```

Whenever I click this component, the all texts of whole app did flickering :/

Comment: Can you share some code? That'll help to understand the problem.

Comment: @AksharPatel thanks you, i did update my code, please help

Comment: hi, did you find any solution?